# laravel cannot display jsondata

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm try to use jsondata to display the results.
This is my output.
Now i just try to display the result

[image]

```
public function resultsurvey($survey_id)
    {
        //$results=[];

        $allResults= Results::where('survey_id', $survey_id)->get()->toArray(); 
        $justResults=Results::select('results')->where('survey_id', $survey_id)->get();

        $json = json_decode($justResults, true);


        $aQuestions = array();
        $aAnswers = array();
        foreach($json as $sKey => $oItem) {
            array_push($aQuestions, $sKey);
            array_push($aAnswers, $oItem);
        }

        dd($aQuestions , $aAnswers);
}
```

in pure php i just use a but in the laravel it's not work.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach($aQuestions as $aQuestionsn){?>
          <th scope="col"><?php echo $aQuestionsn; ?></th>
        <?php }?>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach($aAnswers as $aAnswersn) {?>
            <td><?php echo $aAnswersn;?></td>   
        <?php }?>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How i can display the jsonstring ?

All i need look like this

[image]

Comment: use  `$json = json_encode($justResults, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS);` instead of `$json = json_decode($justResults, true);` if you really need to make any json data. BTW why do you need json in your case?  You can just pass the array from controller to view.

Comment: look at my edit It's will answer your questions

Comment: How does your data column look like when it is saved? If it's escaped with `\"` it probably means your JSON is encoded twice.

Comment: I just saved the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well i think in your case there is another array inside your array you need to go inside that array

```
foreach($aAnswers as $aAnswersn)
{
foreach ($aAnswersn as $value)
{
echo $value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least your `json_encode` is possibly in the wrong location, try this:

```
public function resultsurvey($survey_id)
{
    //$results=[];

    $allResults= Results::where('survey_id', $survey_id)->get()->toArray(); 
    $justResults=Results::select('results')->where('survey_id', $survey_id)->get();

    $aQuestions = array();
    $aAnswers = array();
    // $justResults is a collection so loop through it
    foreach($justResults as $sKey => $oItem) {
        // $oItem is possibly JSON encoded at this stage
        $oItem = json_decode($oItem, true);
        array_push($aQuestions, $sKey);
        array_push($aAnswers, $oItem);
    }

    dd($aQuestions , $aAnswers);
}
```

Please note all changes

Comment: I can't display my code is <div class="container"> 
 <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
  <tr>
  <?php foreach($aQuestions as $aQuestionsn){?>
    <th scope="col"><?php echo $aQuestionsn; ?></th>
  <?php }?>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
  <tr>
  <?php foreach($aAnswers as $aAnswersn) {?>
   <td><?php echo $aAnswersn;?></td> 
  <?php }?>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>